# In Spacy how can I efficiently compare the similarity of one document to all others?

Tags: performance, gensim, spacy

For my application I'm comparing the similarity of one document against all other documents because I want to find the most similar other documents. In Gensim this can be done efficiently using the [MatrixSimilarity method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/similarities/docsim.html).

In Spacy's [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) they have the example for comparing multiple documents, however for many documents the loop is not an efficient implementation:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc1 = nlp(u"The labrador barked.")
doc2 = nlp(u"The labrador swam.")
doc3 = nlp(u"the labrador people live in canada.")

for doc in [doc1, doc2, doc3]:
    labrador = doc[1]
    dog = nlp(u"dog")
    print(labrador.similarity(dog))
```

If someone could please suggest an efficient way compare one document to all others in Spacy it would be much appreciated.

I believe it may involve using a [pipeline](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines), but I'm not sure how to use those.

I'll note that the example above from the documentation seems to have an [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1791), so any ideas for how get around that issue are also welcome.

Comment: Quick comment: if you have to use Spacy (which is awesome, but I am a massive fan of gensim), you're going to have to process each document anyway at some point. Not sure on your application, but you could pre-process, get the raw vectors/norms for these docs and then you should be able to do a simple cosine sim for each input doc. Also see sense2vec, and its ```most_similar``` method (it might help, depending on your use case).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your application and amount of sentences to compare, I would suggest creating an array containing all your sentence vectors, normalized. A matrix multiplication with its transpose would then result in all of the similarity pairs in a rather efficient way.

Comment: How well would this scale? For example if I have 2 million records and want to find a record with similar text to that which the user has just entered, am I correct to assume that pretty much any approach would be very slow, including this one?  If that is possible, then what approach would be best please?  Is spacy similarity an option on a dataset of that size? Thanks :)

Comment: @Doug Were you able to find a solution for better scaling when matching one record with 2 million other records? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: It's a while since I looked at this, but I ended up using word2Vec and doc2Vec if I remember rightly.